How to remove build up in bathroom basin and stop dripping noise?
Why is the water in bathroom basin draining extremely slowly & afterwards bathroom basin makes a dripping sound?
Please assist, what can i do to improve bathroom basins faster water drainage flow and stop the basins dripping sound? Most of all remove build up in bathroom basin where the water flows down and stop dripping noise?
Thank you

You can buy chemical to pour down the sink, you can get a snake/coil to poke holes in the buildup. You can call a plumber.
